# pass an integer variable into vba array formula

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to pass integer value to array formula, below is the code:-

```
cnt = 150
cnt2 = 10
Range("H" & cnt2).Select

Selection.FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Input_Sheet!R1C8:R[" & cnt & "]C8,MATCH(1,(backbone_new!RC[-4]=Input_Sheet!R1C2:R[" & cnt & "]C2)*(backbone_new!RC[-3]=Input_Sheet!R1C4:R[" & cnt & "]C4),0))"
```

I am getting below output in spreadsheet :

```
=INDEX(Input_Sheet!$H$1:$H160,MATCH(1,(backbone_new!D10=Input_Sheet!$B$1:$B160)*(backbone_new!E10=Input_Sheet!$D$1:$D160),0))'
```

Integer cnt value is 150 but I am getting 160 in the formula. Any thoughts?

Comment: You offset by 150, hence you get 160. If you do not want to change RC style, you can declare cnt2 and cnt like this respectively: `cnt2 = 10` and `cnt = 150 - cnt2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use [" & cnt & "] you offset by 150 rows. As you selected a cell in the 10th row, you end up in the 160th row.

The [ ] means offset. If you want the actual row, do it like this:

```
cnt = 150
cnt2 = 10
Range("H" & cnt2).Select

Selection.FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Input_Sheet!R1C8:R" & cnt & "C8,MATCH(1,(backbone_new!RC[-4]=Input_Sheet!R1C2:R" & cnt & "C2)*(backbone_new!RC[-3]=Input_Sheet!R1C4:R" & cnt & "C4),0))"
```

i.e. simply remove the [ ] .