# How to pass dynamic variables to an equation in VBA

Tags: vba, equations

I have an equation in VBA

```
f = Evaluate("index(A2:G27,match(1,(B2:B27=""Apples"")*(C2:C27= ""Oranges""),0),4)")
```

But I would like to be able to refer to the ranges as dynamic, depending on other conditions. For example, another search will be range **A46:G77**, not A2:G27. Also, my matches will change as well to **B46:B77** and **C46:C77**

Is there a way to pass in a variable so that I can alter the range of values used in the search.

I tried

```
f = Evaluate("index(A" & var1 & ":G" & var2 & ",match(1,(B2:B27=""Apples"")*(C2:C27= ""Oranges""),0),4)")
```

to no avail.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

NBB: This question differs from [How to pass variables to an double match function in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49989345/how-to-pass-variables-to-an-double-match-function-in-vba) in that in this question I want the dimension of the referenced matrix to be altered, as my attempt to alter it failed from my background.

Comment: how is this different than your other question?

Comment: Did you only want to change part of your formula?  What about B2:B27 etc ?